# Can't set Art Layer Kind in Photoshop

Tags: python, vbscript, adobe, photoshop

I'm trying to create a tool in Photoshop through python that creates a gradient map layer. When searching through the Adobe VBScript Reference Documentation, the coder is supposed to be able to create a new layer and set its "kind" by executing the following code:

```
GMapLayer = self.doc.artLayers.Add()
GMapLayer.Kind = 13
```

setting the kind to 13 should create a Gradient Map Adjustment layer. The problem is, this code only works for the first 2 out of 23 entries. a kind of 1 creates a standard empty layer, a kind of 2 creates a text layer, all other numbers throw out this error:

_ctypes.COMError: (-2147213311, None, (None, None, None, 0, None))

The documentation from adobe doesn't specify how to use the other 21 constants. Anyone ever encounter this?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why that's happening.

However, there is a scriptlistener workaround. Agreed, it's ugly; but it works!

To add a new gradient adjustment layer:

```
Dim appRef
Set appRef = CreateObject( "Photoshop.Application" )

' Switch off any dialog boxes
appRef.displayDialogs = 3 

appRef.BringToFront



REM =======================================================
DIM objApp
SET objApp = CreateObject("Photoshop.Application")
REM Use dialog mode 3 for show no dialogs
DIM dialogMode
dialogMode = 3
DIM idMk
idMk = objApp.CharIDToTypeID( "Mk  " )
    DIM desc3873
    SET desc3873 = CreateObject( "Photoshop.ActionDescriptor" )
    DIM idnull
    idnull = objApp.CharIDToTypeID( "null" )
        DIM ref1360
        SET ref1360 = CreateObject( "Photoshop.ActionReference" )
        DIM idAdjL
        idAdjL = objApp.CharIDToTypeID( "AdjL" )
        Call ref1360.PutClass( idAdjL )
    Call desc3873.PutReference( idnull, ref1360 )
    DIM idUsng
    idUsng = objApp.CharIDToTypeID( "Usng" )
        DIM desc3874
        SET desc3874 = CreateObject( "Photoshop.ActionDescriptor" )
        DIM idType
        idType = objApp.CharIDToTypeID( "Type" )
            DIM desc3875
            SET desc3875 = CreateObject( "Photoshop.ActionDescriptor" )
            DIM idGrad
            idGrad = objApp.CharIDToTypeID( "Grad" )
                DIM desc3876
                SET desc3876 = CreateObject( "Photoshop.ActionDescriptor" )
                DIM idNm
                idNm = objApp.CharIDToTypeID( "Nm  " )
                Call desc3876.PutString( idNm, "Foreground to Background" )
                DIM idGrdF
                idGrdF = objApp.CharIDToTypeID( "GrdF" )
                DIM idCstS
                idCstS = objApp.CharIDToTypeID( "CstS" )
                Call desc3876.PutEnumerated( idGrdF, idGrdF, idCstS )
                DIM idIntr
                idIntr = objApp.CharIDToTypeID( "Intr" )
                Call desc3876.PutDouble( idIntr, 4096.000000 )
                DIM idClrs
                idClrs = objApp.CharIDToTypeID( "Clrs" )
                    DIM list470
                    SET list470 = CreateObject( "Photoshop.ActionList" )
                        DIM desc3877
                        SET desc3877 = CreateObject( "Photoshop.ActionDescriptor" )
                        DIM idClr
                        idClr = objApp.CharIDToTypeID( "Clr " )
                            DIM desc3878
                            SET desc3878 = CreateObject( "Photoshop.ActionDescriptor" )
                            DIM idRd
                            idRd = objApp.CharIDToTypeID( "Rd  " )
                            Call desc3878.PutDouble( idRd, 0.000000 )
                            DIM idGrn
                            idGrn = objApp.CharIDToTypeID( "Grn " )
                            Call desc3878.PutDouble( idGrn, 0.000000 )
                            DIM idBl
                            idBl = objApp.CharIDToTypeID( "Bl  " )
                            Call desc3878.PutDouble( idBl, 0.000000 )
                        DIM idRGBC
                        idRGBC = objApp.CharIDToTypeID( "RGBC" )
                        Call desc3877.PutObject( idClr, idRGBC, desc3878 )
                        DIM idType2
                        idType2 = objApp.CharIDToTypeID( "Type" )
                        DIM idClry
                        idClry = objApp.CharIDToTypeID( "Clry" )
                        DIM idUsrS
                        idUsrS = objApp.CharIDToTypeID( "UsrS" )
                        Call desc3877.PutEnumerated( idType2, idClry, idUsrS )
                        DIM idLctn
                        idLctn = objApp.CharIDToTypeID( "Lctn" )
                        Call desc3877.PutInteger( idLctn, 0 )
                        DIM idMdpn
                        idMdpn = objApp.CharIDToTypeID( "Mdpn" )
                        Call desc3877.PutInteger( idMdpn, 50 )
                    DIM idClrt
                    idClrt = objApp.CharIDToTypeID( "Clrt" )
                    Call list470.PutObject( idClrt, desc3877 )
                        DIM desc3879
                        SET desc3879 = CreateObject( "Photoshop.ActionDescriptor" )
                        DIM idClr2
                        idClr2 = objApp.CharIDToTypeID( "Clr " )
                            DIM desc3880
                            SET desc3880 = CreateObject( "Photoshop.ActionDescriptor" )
                            DIM idRd2
                            idRd2 = objApp.CharIDToTypeID( "Rd  " )
                            Call desc3880.PutDouble( idRd2, 255.000000 )
                            DIM idGrn2
                            idGrn2 = objApp.CharIDToTypeID( "Grn " )
                            Call desc3880.PutDouble( idGrn2, 255.000000 )
                            DIM idBl2
                            idBl2 = objApp.CharIDToTypeID( "Bl  " )
                            Call desc3880.PutDouble( idBl2, 255.000000 )
                        DIM idRGBC2
                        idRGBC2 = objApp.CharIDToTypeID( "RGBC" )
                        Call desc3879.PutObject( idClr2, idRGBC2, desc3880 )
                        DIM idType3
                        idType3 = objApp.CharIDToTypeID( "Type" )
                        DIM idClry2
                        idClry2 = objApp.CharIDToTypeID( "Clry" )
                        DIM idUsrS2
                        idUsrS2 = objApp.CharIDToTypeID( "UsrS" )
                        Call desc3879.PutEnumerated( idType3, idClry2, idUsrS2 )
                        DIM idLctn2
                        idLctn2 = objApp.CharIDToTypeID( "Lctn" )
                        Call desc3879.PutInteger( idLctn2, 4096 )
                        DIM idMdpn2
                        idMdpn2 = objApp.CharIDToTypeID( "Mdpn" )
                        Call desc3879.PutInteger( idMdpn2, 50 )
                    DIM idClrt2
                    idClrt2 = objApp.CharIDToTypeID( "Clrt" )
                    Call list470.PutObject( idClrt2, desc3879 )
                Call desc3876.PutList( idClrs, list470 )
                DIM idTrns
                idTrns = objApp.CharIDToTypeID( "Trns" )
                    DIM list471
                    SET list471 = CreateObject( "Photoshop.ActionList" )
                        DIM desc3881
                        SET desc3881 = CreateObject( "Photoshop.ActionDescriptor" )
                        DIM idOpct
                        idOpct = objApp.CharIDToTypeID( "Opct" )
                        DIM idPrc
                        idPrc = objApp.CharIDToTypeID( "#Prc" )
                        Call desc3881.PutUnitDouble( idOpct, idPrc, 100.000000 )
                        DIM idLctn3
                        idLctn3 = objApp.CharIDToTypeID( "Lctn" )
                        Call desc3881.PutInteger( idLctn3, 0 )
                        DIM idMdpn3
                        idMdpn3 = objApp.CharIDToTypeID( "Mdpn" )
                        Call desc3881.PutInteger( idMdpn3, 50 )
                    DIM idTrnS3
                    idTrnS3 = objApp.CharIDToTypeID( "TrnS" )
                    Call list471.PutObject( idTrnS3, desc3881 )
                        DIM desc3882
                        SET desc3882 = CreateObject( "Photoshop.ActionDescriptor" )
                        DIM idOpct3
                        idOpct3 = objApp.CharIDToTypeID( "Opct" )
                        DIM idPrc3
                        idPrc3 = objApp.CharIDToTypeID( "#Prc" )
                        Call desc3882.PutUnitDouble( idOpct3, idPrc3, 100.000000 )
                        DIM idLctn4
                        idLctn4 = objApp.CharIDToTypeID( "Lctn" )
                        Call desc3882.PutInteger( idLctn4, 4096 )
                        DIM idMdpn4
                        idMdpn4 = objApp.CharIDToTypeID( "Mdpn" )
                        Call desc3882.PutInteger( idMdpn4, 50 )
                    DIM idTrnS4
                    idTrnS4 = objApp.CharIDToTypeID( "TrnS" )
                    Call list471.PutObject( idTrnS4, desc3882 )
                Call desc3876.PutList( idTrns4, list471 )
            DIM idGrdn
            idGrdn = objApp.CharIDToTypeID( "Grdn" )
            Call desc3875.PutObject( idGrad, idGrdn, desc3876 )
        DIM idGdMp
        idGdMp = objApp.CharIDToTypeID( "GdMp" )
        Call desc3874.PutObject( idType, idGdMp, desc3875 )
    DIM idAdjL2
    idAdjL2 = objApp.CharIDToTypeID( "AdjL" )
    Call desc3873.PutObject( idUsng, idAdjL2, desc3874 )
Call objApp.ExecuteAction( idMk, desc3873, dialogMode )
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason is that the available adjustments over COM are only the destructive adjustments in Image>Adjustments not the actual `AdjustmentLayers`. for example: `AdjustBrightnessContrast`.

When creating a new `ArtLayer` it creates a normal layer and when setting its type to text with `psTextLayer` it converts that layer into a text layer in the same way as if you'd use the Type tool on a normal Layer.

The `PsLayerKind 3-24` are read only and can be used in IF statements.

Here is an example how to utilise the types in an ExtendScript loop:

```
var doc = app.activeDocument;
var layers = doc.artLayers;

for (var i = 0; i < layers.length; i++) {
    var layer = layers[i];
    if (layer.kind == LayerKind.GRADIENTMAP) {
        // do something here
    }
}
```

Where as over a COM connection for example in Python you'd have to do this:

```
doc = app.Application.ActiveDocument
layers = doc.ArtLayers
GradientMapLayer = 13

for layer in layers:
    if layer.Kind is GradientMapLayer:
        # do something here
```